# Is it possible to build a steering system without using gear racks such as part 87761?

Tags: technic

Is it possible to use part 6575 (and together with other Technic pieces) as an alternative to part 87761 for a steering system? (I am trying to use Technic pieces from Technic 42030 set to simulate this [MOC](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/ChristophBartneck/nano-racer)). If possible, how do I go about it?

Part 87761

[image]

Part 6575

[image]

Comment: To be honest, these parts don't seem to have anything to do with each other. You may wish to have a look at another question dealing with replacing 87761: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/alternative-for-technic-gear-rack-1-x-7-with-axle-and-pin-holes

Comment: What specifically are you trying to design? If you're trying to do something specific with the gear rack (e.g. create a steering system), we might be able to help you come up with alternative designs, but without knowing that, it's hard to see how the two parts you mentioned would be replacements for one another.

Comment: @jncraton, Thanks for the feedback, I have added my specification to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to build a steering system without using a gear rack. Rack and pinion steering is simply one of the easiest ways to translate the rotational motion of a steering wheel to the translational motion needed to adjust the wheels.

Here's [one example](http://www.moc-pages.com/moc.php/320971) of using tie rods and a knuckle to accomplish steering:

[image: Tie rods and knuckle]

That's obviously quite complicated because it incorporates suspension as well as steering, but it's too pretty to not include. This basic concept is what is often used on go carts because it's dead simple, and mechanical advantage isn't very important on vehicles that small:

[image: go cart steering]

This design can be simplified to not need ball joints as long as all the moving parts stay in the same plane. Here's an example of Ackermann steering implemented that way:

[image: Ackermann steering]

You could swap 6575 into that design instead of 2825 pretty easily.

Here's an [even simpler](https://mindstormspodcast.wordpress.com/building-instructions/ackermann-steering-geometry/) example with a motor mounted perpendicularly to avoid even needing to use any gears:

[image: Perpendicular motor mount]

Comment: You can even use the requested part 6575 in your first design